# unable to get the transposed data in a particular format in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below:

```
import pandas as pd

df_vals = {'A':['X','Y','Z','X','Y','Z'],
           'B':[23,12,68,2,6,15],
           'C':[34,11,256,321,138,56],
           'D':['02-Feb-14',    '04-Mar-14',    '23-Jan-13',    '18-Feb-14',    '02-Jun-14',    '04-Aug-13']
           }

# Creating the DataFrame

df = pd.DataFrame(data=df_vals)

print(df) # Prints the created dataframe
```

I used the below code:

```
# Way : 1
df1_transposed = df.T
print(df1_transposed)
```

This is not returning the results as expected.

Neither the below code :

```
# Way : 2
df2_transposed = df.transpose()
print(df2_transposed)
```

What I want to transpose the data to look something like in the below snapshot:

[image]

Comment: why does `Source` row `X` become `Target` column `Z`?

Comment: i guess that's a typo and `Target` column `Z` should be `[68, 256, 23-Jan-13]`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct tdy, thanks for noticing, it is typo. Column X had that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with this solution you have to know the final number of columns, in your example 3:
first of, you need to set the index of the dataframe to 'A' and then traspose:

```
df1_transposed = df.set_index('A').T
```

now, you have to concat consecutive slices of your dataframe:

```
pd.concat([df1_transposed.iloc[:,i*3:i*3+3] for i in 
           range(0,int(np.ceil(len(df1_transposed.columns)/3)))], axis=0)
```

in this case you want to group columns 3 by 3, if your columns was W, X, Y, Z you have to replace with

```
pd.concat([df1_transposed.iloc[:,i*4:i*4+4] for i in 
           range(0,int(np.ceil(len(df1_transposed.columns)/4)))], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pivot (`set_index+unstack`) using a helper column (`df.groupby+cumcount`) and then transpose finally drop the unwanted index.

```
out = (df.set_index(["A",df.groupby("A").cumcount()]).unstack()
        .T.sort_index(level=-1)
        .droplevel(-1).rename_axis(None,axis=1))
```

---

```
print(out)

           X          Y          Z
B         23         12         68
C         34         11        256
D  02-Feb-14  04-Mar-14  23-Jan-13
B          2          6         15
C        321        138         56
D  18-Feb-14  02-Jun-14  04-Aug-13
```

Comment: nice, what's `level=-1`?

Comment: @tdy thank you, it refers to the last level (here second level)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
pd.concat([df.set_index('A')[i:i+3][[k for k in df.columns if k!='A']].T for i in range(0, df.shape[0], 3)])

A          X          Y          Z
B         23         12         68
C         34         11        256
D  02-Feb-14  04-Mar-14  23-Jan-13
B          2          6         15
C        321        138         56
D  18-Feb-14  02-Jun-14  04-Aug-13
```

Comment: thanks for help, this code will not be generic.. if I had more than just the three B, C, D rows under column 'A', right?

Comment: Yes it's a custom solution, based on your input, however it's easy amendable and can be generalized with some additional code

Comment: I made it more generic now, please take a look